# Python threads in C

Tags: python, c, multithreading

I'am writing a multi-threaded program in C. Before creating the threads, a global python environment is initialized by calling [`Py_Initialize()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html?highlight=py_ini#Py_Initialize). Then, in every created thread, the global python environment is shared, and each thread calls a python method with the parameters converted in C. Everything works well until here.

When I use `time.sleep()` in loaded python modules, the C program raises a `Segmentation Fault`. Furthermore, the loaded python module is supposed to load another C lib to continue the work. I've written the following stupid counter lib to test it:

```py
# python part, call the counter function
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpycount.so)
for i in xrange(10):
    lib.count()
```

```c
// C part, dummy countings
#include <stdio.h>
int counter = 1;
void
count() {
    printf("counter:%d \n", counter);
    counter++;
}
```

I guess that it might be because I didn't manage the complex thread creation in the right way. And I've found [`Non-Python created threads`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads) in the python doc.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Did you actually follow the advice in that document you found? How are you grabbing the GIL in the code that calls into Python?

Comment: @Thomas Wouters I've used `PyGILState_STATE gstate;`, `gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();` and `PyGILState_Release(gstate);` as they are mentioned in the doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem has been solved. You may have your problems more particular, so I'm trying to write my solution in a more generic way here. Hope it helps.

### - In main C thread

- initialize the Python environment at the very begining:

```c
/*define a global variable to store the main python thread state*/
PyThreadState * mainThreadState = NULL;

if(!Py_IsInitialized())
    Py_Initialize();

mainThreadState = = PyThreadState_Get();
```

- Then start the C threads:

```c
pthread_create(pthread_id, NULL, thread_entrance, NULL);
```

### - In every thread, or we can say in the body of thread_entrance function

- prepare the environment:

```c
/*get the lock and create new python thread state*/
PyEval_AcquireLock();
PyInterpreterState * mainInterpreterState = mainThreadState->interp;
PyThreadState * myThreadState = PyThreadState_New(mainInterpreterState);
PyEval_ReleaseLock();    /*don't forget to release the lock*/

/*
 * some C manipulations here
 */
```

- put embeded Python code here:

```c
/*get the lock and put your C-Python code here*/
PyEval_AcquireLock();
PyThreadState_Swap(myThreadState);    /*swap your python thread state*/

PyEval_CallObject(py_function, py_arguments);
/*or just something like PyRun_SimpleString("print \"hello world\""); for test*/

PyThreadState_Swap(NULL);    /*clean the thread state before leaving*/
PyEval_ReleaseLock();
```

### - back to main C thread

- when every thread finishes their works, finalize the python environment

```c
pthread_join(pthread_id, NULL);
PyEval_RestoreThread(mainThreadState);
Py_Finalize();
```

Answer (score 2):

Question is whether the Python interpreter is thread safe -- This is what the documentation says about running multiple interpreters in the same process space;

> Bugs and caveats: Because sub-interpreters (and the main interpreter)
>   are part of the same process, the insulation between them isn't
>   perfect -- for example, using low-level file operations like
>   os.close() they can (accidentally or maliciously) affect each other's
>   open files. Because of the way extensions are shared between
>   (sub-)interpreters, some extensions may not work properly; this is
>   especially likely when the extension makes use of (static) global
>   variables, or when the extension manipulates its module's dictionary
>   after its initialization. It is possible to insert objects created in
>   one sub-interpreter into a namespace of another sub-interpreter; this
>   should be done with great care to avoid sharing user-defined
>   functions, methods, instances or classes between sub-interpreters,
>   since import operations executed by such objects may affect the wrong
>   (sub-)interpreter's dictionary of loaded modules. (XXX This is a
>   hard-to-fix bug that will be addressed in a future release.)

...and I don't think that Python threads are the same thing as native threads such as found in C/C++